# Bash Script to Sort Files into Alphabetical Folders on ReadyNAS Duo v1

Tags: bash, files, scripting

I have an old ReadyNAS Duo v1 (Sparc) running an unknown flavour of Linux.

I have a folder structure with 1,000+ files I want to move into a folder structure based on the first letter of the file name (case insensitive).

Ideally I'd like the file structure to look like this:

```
myfiles-+
        +-A
          + Apple.txt
          + avocado.txt
        +-B
          + Banana.txt
          + broccoli.txt
etc. etc.
```

I've had a Google but have only found GUI tools.

Can this be done via the command line or a script?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a bit of a one liner that will do what you want:

```
$ mkdir -p output/{A..Z}; for i in tstdir/*; do export FILE=$(basename "$i");  LTR=$(echo" ${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]); mv "$i" "output/$LTR/$FILE" ; done
```

Here's the same command in expanded form so you can see what's going on:

```
$ mkdir -p output/{A..Z}
$ for i in tstdir/*; do 
    FILE=$(basename "$i")  
    LTR=$(echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
    mv "$i" "output/$LTR/$FILE"
  done
```

#### Details

The above first assumes that the output directory of just the letters doesn't exist and so will create it,

```
$ mkdir -p output/{A..Z}
```

The `for` loop works as follows, looping through all the files in `tstdir/*`. It then determines the `basename` of this path, and stores it in the variable, `$FILE`. Each iteration through the loop is stored in the variable `$i`.

```
FILE=$(basename "$i")
```

We then use Bashes ability to return the 1st character of the named variable, `$FILE`, and then use `tr` to convert any lowercase characters to uppers.

```
LTR=$(echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z])
```

Breaking this down a bit more:

```
$ echo "${FILE:0:1}"
s
$ echo "${FILE:0:1}"
T
```

With the `tr` code you can now see what's going on:

```
$ echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]
S
$ echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]
T
```

The rest of the command just moves the files into their corresponding first letter directory.

#### Example

Say we have this directory of files:

```
$ touch {a-z}file {A-Z}file

$ tree tstdir/ | head -10
tstdir/
|-- afile
|-- Afile
|-- bfile
|-- Bfile
|-- cfile
|-- Cfile
|-- dfile
|-- Dfile
|-- efile
...
```

After running the one liner:

```
$ tree output/ | head -10
output/
|-- A
|   |-- afile
|   `-- Afile
|-- B
|   |-- bfile
|   `-- Bfile
|-- C
|   |-- cfile
|   `-- Cfile
...
```

Comment: Good job, to undo this batch I make `mv */*.* .` (I don't know if this is the best way but it's work for me).

Answer (score 3):

With `zsh`

```
mkmv() {mkdir -p -- $argv[-1]:h && mv "$@"}
autoload zmv
zmodload zsh/files

zmv -Qp mkmv '(?)*(^-/)' '${(U)1}/$f'
```

- [`zmv`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zmv) a function to safely batch-rename files using zsh powerful pattern matching and expansion operators as an autoloadable function.
- `mkmv`: a function that acts like `mv` except that it also creates the parent directory of the target if need be.
- `$argv[-1]`: `$argv` like `$*` is the list of positional parameters, `$argv[-1]` is the last one. Here, same as `$3` as `zmv` calls it as `mkmv -- source destination`
- `$var:h`: like in `csh`, [gets the *head* of the variable, that is the dir name](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers).
- `zmodload zsh/files`: loads a [module](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Zsh-Modules.html#The-zsh_002ffiles-Module) that enables the builtin version of a few file handling utilities including `mkdir` and `mv`, here giving a significative performance enhancement as we're calling both for each file.
- `-Q`: enable *bare* glob qualifiers in the pattern. Theses days, another option is to rewrite `(^-/)` as `(#q^-/)`.
- `-p mkmv`, tell `zmv` to use our `mkmv` function as the program to do the renaming instead of `mv`
- `(?)*(^-/)`: a pattern `(?)*` with a glob qualifier used to match the files to rename. The `?` (to match a single character) in parenthesis is *captured* so it can be referred to as `$1` in the replacement.
- `(^-/)`: [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) used to match files based on more criteria than just their name:

  - `^`: negate the following qualifiers
  - `-`: for the following qualifiers, for symlinks, consider the attribute of the target of the link instead of the link itself.
  - `/`: select files of type directory. With the previous two  qualifiers, that means we want files that are neither directories nor symlinks to directories.
- `${(U)1}`: the captured first character of the matched file, converted to uppercase with the `U` [parameter expansion flag](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Parameter-Expansion-Flags)
- `$f` in the replacement refers to the full path of the matched file.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what each part does?

Comment: @MaxMatti, see edit

Answer (score 2):

Try with this script:

```
for first in $(ls -1 | sed 's/^\(.\).*$/\1/' | tr '[a-z0-9]' '[A-Z0-9]' | uniq)
do
    mkdir tmp
    mv "$first"* tmp/
    lower=$(echo $first | tr '[A-Z]' '[a-z]')
    mv "$lower"* tmp/
    mv tmp/ "$first";
done
```

The logic is as follows:

1. List all the files in the current directory.
2. Extract the first character with `sed`.
3. Change the first character to lower case with `tr`, this is to reduce the number of comparisons.
4. Remove duplicates with `uniq`.
5. Create a temporary directory and move all the files that start with the character to this folder.
6. Rename the temporary file.

I used these files to test the script:

```
Apple.txt
avocado.txt
banana.txt
broccoli.txt
car.txt
dddd.txt
delete.txt
zaad.txt
zdfa.txt
```

Here is the result:

```
.
├── A
│   ├── Apple.txt
│   └── avocado.txt
├── B
│   ├── banana.txt
│   └── broccoli.txt
├── C
│   └── car.txt
├── D
│   ├── dddd.txt
│   └── delete.txt
└── Z
    ├── zaad.txt
    └── zdfa.txt

5 directories, 10 files
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a brute force approach:

```
for i in {a..z}; do 
 upper=$(printf "%s\n" $i | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'); 
 ls -1 | grep -i "^$i" 2>/dev/null 1>&2 && mkdir -p $upper && 
 mv "$i*" "$u*" $u/ 2>/dev/null; 
done
```

This will iterate through all letters (`{a..z}`), convert them to capitals (`tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'`), check if any file begins with that letter (`ls -1 | grep -i $i`) and if so, create the directory with the capital letter as name (`mkdir -p $upper`) and then move all files starting with the letter in question (both lowercase and capital) into the corresponding folder.

Since you're running this on a NAS and probably have a minimal shell installed, the `{a..z}` format might not work. If so, do this instead (I *said* this was a brute force approach):

```
for i in a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z; do 
 upper=$(printf "%s\n" $i | tr '[a-z]' '[A-Z]'); 
 ls -1 | grep -i "^$i" 2>/dev/null 1>&2 && mkdir -p $upper && 
 mv "$i*" "$u*" $u/ 2>/dev/null; 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

To improve upon SLM's answer you can also make this work for files that start with a number by creating 0-9 directories:

```
mkdir -p output/{A..Z}; mkdir -p output/{0..9}; for i in tstdir/*; do export FILE=$(basename "$i"); LTR=$(echo "${FILE:0:1}" | tr [a-z] [A-Z]); mv "$i" "output/$LTR/$FILE" ; done
```